# Upfront active menu link

Tags: javascript, css

I use Javascript that will decorate an active link after it's been clicked. Question is, how can I load the page with one of the menu items already active?

Example: http://moschalkx.nl/

Javascript code:

```
function hlite_menu(obj) {
    var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('A');
    for (var i in lnk) {
        lnk[i].className = (lnk[i] === obj) ? 'menu_active' : 'menu_idle';
    }
}

function set_menu() {
    var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('A');
    for (var i in lnk) {
        lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle';
        lnk[i].onclick = function () {
            hlite_menu(this);
        }
    }
    if (lnk[i]) { /* ??? how do you know whether this is the link to activeate up front? */
        hlist_menu(lnk[i]);
    }
}
window.onload = set_menu;
```

CSS:

```
a.menu_idle {color:#333333; text-decoration:none;}
a.menu_active {color:#333333; text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited {color:#333333; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#333333; text-decoration:underline;}
```

I need to put in the logic somewhere inside

```
if (lnk[i]) { /* ??? how do you know whether this is the link to activeate up front? */
    hlist_menu(lnk[i]);
}
```

to let the script know which link will be active upfront. As i'm not familiar with coding, i have no clue how to do this!

Comment: What do you mean by "active upfront"? Looking at your page, none of the pages that the links point to are active. If I'm viewing your site correctly, all of the links load into an `iframe` which doesn't have any of the links targets active as its content. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: hi pete, the script will decorate an active link after clicking it, i would like to start with a link decorated as an active link. does that makes sense?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense (but not from a user experience perspective because none of the targets are actually active by default). Out of the four links, which should be the active one by default? Currently `gallery/splash_gallery.html` is active by default but there's no link for it (although you could wrap the `MO SCHALKX` "logo" in a link that points to it and make it the active link by default). If instead you were to make `BLOG` the default active link it would make sense to have `http://reflecture.tumblr.com/` the default active link. Or did you want a random link to be "active" by default?

Comment: yes you're absolutely right, it wouldn't make sense to have a link active by default right now. I was thinking of starting with `gallery/photo_menu.html` open in the iframe, and have PHOTOGRAPHY (the link) active by default. Also when you click PHOTOGRAPHY (or film) in the top menu, you'll see a sub menu in the down left corner. In this menu it is much more important to start with the link ALL active as default. As the overview open at start will be all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initially active link in your markup:

```
<a target="iframe1" class="menu_active" href="gallery/photo_menu.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
```

Then in your `set_menu` function, set the `iframe`'s `src` attribute to the `href` of that link:

```
for (i in lnk) {
    if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        //lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle'; // initial menu states are set in markup. This line is no longer necessary.
        lnk[i].onclick = hlite_menu;
        if (lnk[i].className === 'menu_active') {
            iframe.src = lnk[i].href;
        }
    }
}
```

I would also strongly recommend re-writing your JavaScript to the following:

```
var hlite_menu = function hlite_menu() {
    'use strict';
    var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        i = null;
    //set all links to idle
    for (i in lnk) {
        if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle';
        }
    }
    //set this link to active
    this.className = 'menu_active';
},
set_menu = function set_menu() {
    'use strict';
    var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1'),
        c = document.getElementById('copyright'),
        i = null;
    // set copyright
    c.innerText = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    // set onclicks and initial iframe src.
    for (i in lnk) {
        if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            //lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle'; // initial menu states are set in markup. This line is no longer necessary.
            lnk[i].onclick = hlite_menu;
            if (lnk[i].className === 'menu_active') {
                iframe.src = lnk[i].href;
            }
        }
    }
};
window.onload = set_menu;
```

This avoids several long-term problems like readability/maintenance, [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), and the dreaded `document.write` (which you are using to set your copyright date). You'll also want to change the copyright section to this:

```
<div id="footer">
    ALL IMAGES &#169; <span id="copyright"></span>
</div>
```

You can also write your navigation like this (avoiding tables for layout):

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <span style="">MO SCHALKX</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a target="iframe1" class="menu_active" href="gallery/photo_menu.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
        <a target="iframe1" class="menu_idle" href="gallery/film_menu.html">FILM</a>
        <a target="iframe1" class="menu_idle" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a target="iframe1" class="menu_idle" href="http://reflecture.tumblr.com">BLOG</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add this to your CSS:

```
#header {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo, #menu {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: inherit;
}

#menu {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#menu > a {
    padding-left: 0.25em;
}
#menu > a {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

#menu > a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```

which should make it look the same. You can also combine your CSS rules for `menu_active` and `a:hover` (likewise with `menu_idle` and `a:visited`) like so:

```
a.menu_idle, a:visited {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.menu_active, a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Finally, you've wrapped your `iframe` in a `<form id="form1" runat="server">` element. You can remove this entirely. It won't affect your layout and you don't actually have a form with any `input` elements so it's unnecessary. Also, the `runat="server"` attribute doesn't do anything unless you're running this on ASP.Net (and you obviously are not) so you may want to keep that in mind.

Altogether, you should be able to change the entire document source to the following with no real visual changes (and I think you'll find that it's a lot cleaner to look at in the source):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Mo Schalkx Photography</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var hlite_menu = function hlite_menu() {
        'use strict';
        var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
            i = null;
        //set all links to idle
        for (i in lnk) {
            if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle';
            }
        }
        //set this link to active
        this.className = 'menu_active';
    },
    set_menu = function set_menu() {
        'use strict';
        var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
            iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1'),
            c = document.getElementById('copyright'),
            i = null;
        // set copyright
        c.innerText = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        // set onclicks and initial iframe src.
        for (i in lnk) {
            if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                //lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle'; // initial menu states are set in markup. This line is no longer necessary.
                lnk[i].onclick = hlite_menu;
                if (lnk[i].className === 'menu_active') {
                    iframe.src = lnk[i].href;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    window.onload = set_menu;
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    #header {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1em;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #iframe1 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        #footer {
            font-size: 9px;
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            visibility: visible;
            display: block;
            color: #000;
            opacity: 0.4;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* 50% white from bottom */;
        }

        .logo, #menu {
            background-color: #FFF;
        }

        .logo {
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: inherit;
        }

        #menu {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #menu > a {
            padding-left: 0.25em;
        }
        #menu > a {
            border-left: 1px solid #000;
        }

        #menu > a:first-child {
            border-left: none;
        }

        a.menu_idle, a:visited {
            color: #333333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a.menu_active, a:hover {
            color: #333333;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <span style="">MO SCHALKX</span>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <a target="iframe1" class="menu_active" href="gallery/photo_menu.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
            <a target="iframe1" class="menu_idle" href="gallery/film_menu.html">FILM</a>
            <a target="iframe1" class="menu_idle" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
            <a target="iframe1" class="menu_idle" href="http://reflecture.tumblr.com">BLOG</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        ALL IMAGES &#169; <span id="copyright"></span>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**UDPATE**

To apply this on http://moschalkx.nl/gallery/film_menu.html, simply include the same JavaScript and comment out the lines that involve setting the copyright in `set_menu` and update the `id` of the `iframe`:

```
var hlite_menu = function hlite_menu() {
    'use strict';
    var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        i = null;
    //set all links to idle
    for (i in lnk) {
        if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle';
        }
    }
    //set this link to active
    this.className = 'menu_active';
},
set_menu = function set_menu() {
    'use strict';
    var lnk = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        iframe = document.getElementById('gallery'),
        //c = document.getElementById('copyright'),
        i = null;
    // set copyright
    //c.innerText = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    // set onclicks and initial iframe src.
    for (i in lnk) {
        if (lnk.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            //lnk[i].className = 'menu_idle'; // initial menu states are set in markup. This line is no longer necessary.
            lnk[i].onclick = hlite_menu;
            if (lnk[i].className === 'menu_active') {
                iframe.src = lnk[i].href;
            }
        }
    }
};
window.onload = set_menu;
```

Also, since you're including jQuery on this page, you could write that in jQuery as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu a').click(function (e) {
        var self = $(this),
            href = self.attr('href');
        $('#menu a').not(self).removeClass('menu_active').addClass('menu_idle');
        self.removeClass('menu_idle').addClass('menu_active');
        $('#gallery').attr('src', href);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi pete! thank you so so much! this was exactly wat i was looking for and so much more haha! the menu works great! only one last question, i was trying to implement this same function to the bottom menu (+ menu) although this doesn't seem to work. i'm probably doing something wrom, could you possibly find the time to look at it?